# How I can allow displaybreak long equations?

Tags: equations

I have many long equation in my theses. There are problems in my pdf file. How it is possible displaybreak equations throughout an article?
[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{document}‎
Hi
‎\begin{equation}‎
‎\begin{align}‎ 
  ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎
  ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
 \end{align}‎
‎\end{equation}‎‎
Allow display breaks everywhere‎
‎
Hi
‎\begin{equation}‎
‎\begin{align}‎ 
  ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎
  ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
 \end{align}‎
‎\end{equation}‎‎
Allow display breaks everywhere

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `equation` spoils the action of `\allowdisplaybreaks`. (I am assuming that the picture with 4 resulting pages is unneeded here).

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{document}‎
Hi
%‎\begin{equation}‎
‎\begin{align}‎ 
  ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎
  ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
 \end{align}‎
‎%\end{equation}‎‎
Allow display breaks everywhere‎
‎
Hi
‎%\begin{equation}‎
‎\begin{align}‎ 
  ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎
  ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
           ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ 
   ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
     ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
       ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\ ‎‎
         ‎& ‎a‎ ‎\\‎ ‎‎‎‎
 \end{align}‎
%‎\end{equation}‎‎
Allow display breaks everywhere

\end{document}
```